# Find elapsed time of sidekiq job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

Is there an easy method to see the elapsed time of a `sidekiq` job?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log output?

```
ScheduledWorker JID-072f6c37f240a92ca3c07914 INFO: start
ScheduledWorker JID-072f6c37f240a92ca3c07914 INFO: done: 0.003 sec
```

Comment: Latest Sidekiq omits `sec`, eg `elapsed=1.698`, so I wasn't clear on the units of the output.